# Creating an Instance with a Variable Child Class Identity (w\o instanceof cases\if-else-)

Tags: java

my question is this: 
is there a way to create an instance based on a Class that is part of a 100 child classes of a Parent Class. And you have a variable that could be 1 of those 100 child classes but you are not sure which one. and you need create an instance of **that** class. But due to the high amount of child classes it would be impractical to find out manually in a case\if-else statement is there a way you may create a new instance based on the variable you have like so:

```
object_2 = new (type of object_1)();
```

Or must you do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mixture of Java Generics and reflection to get what you want. Here's an example of one potential implementation, using `ChildA` and `ChildB` as subclasses of `Parent`:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Test().test();
    }

    private void test() {
        Parent a = new ChildA();
        getNewInstance(a);

        Parent b = new ChildB();
        getNewInstance(b);
    }

    // T extends Parent makes sure we can only pass in subclasses of Parent
    static <T extends Parent> T getNewInstance(T oldInstance) {
        Class<T> theClass = (Class<T>) oldInstance.getClass();

        try {
            return theClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

class Parent {}

class ChildA extends Parent {
    public ChildA() { System.out.println("New ChildA created."); } 
}

class ChildB extends Parent {
    public ChildB() { System.out.println("New ChildB created."); }
}
```

And the output, showing that four separate Child objects were created:

```
New ChildA created.
New ChildA created.
New ChildB created.
New ChildB created.
```

It's worth mentioning that this gets a whole lot more complicated if you need to call parameterised constructors.

There are also a number of other ways to do this using if-else or switch statements, but you specified that you didn't want if-else, and I assumed that that applied to switch as well. Have a read around about the Factory design pattern for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do some reflection...

EDIT:

Sorry, I cannot test code now, but it should be something like this

```
ObjectParent cls = Class.forname(object1.getClass().getCanonicalName()).newInstance();
```

Adding arguments:

To give arguments to the constructor you need to get the constructor of that object:

```
ObjectParent cls = object1.getClass().getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("string");
```

Here youare saying: give me the constructor that have and string as parameter and call it with this string ("string").

Comment: :/ doesnt seem to work. there is no .getConstructor().

Comment: Thanks ^_^ now not neccesary but is it possible to use this with constructors that have parameters? for future reference.

Comment: @GameMasterJack Edited again :P